# Community Nickname along with Number

Tags: community, partner-communities

Hi Guys,
                  I know that Community Nickname  is  system generated fields and they automatically take values once user record is created. In case of Self registration user.

I removed the Community Nickname from the Self registration  Community page and i  want to show the community nickname along with some number  automatically generated when user registered in community ? Is It possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this instead since you're doing this in code anyways. String NickName = LastNameFirstName Query all users where CommunityNickname Starts With NickName If Query results > 0 then NickName = NickName + QuerySize+ 1